# For long-lived connections, how do you test a Salesforce object to make sure the session is still valid, since there is no disconnect?

Tags: python, python-3.x, salesforce

I'm using `simple_salesforce` with Python to connect to a Salesforce database (as you do). I have written a routine to handle the resetting of a Salesforce connection if the session is found to be invalid.

```
def connect(reset=False):
    """ Tiny helper function to connect to Salesforce using env vars """
    global _SF
    if _SF and not reset:
        return _SF
    _SF = Salesforce(**_CREDENTIALS)
    return _SF
```

But I am wondering if there is a better way to test if a Salesforce session is valid rather than catching the `SalesforceExpiredSession` exception and issuing a reset using the above function. E.g.:

```
try:
    result = sf.query_all(statement)
except SalesforceExpiredSession:
    sf = connect(reset=True)
    result = sf.query_all(statement)
```

Is there a better way?